# Store value in variable or call HashMap function?

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

When you need to call a `HashMap`'s `get` on the same value a few times within a for loop, would it be more efficient to store it in a variable or to make the call two or three times?

Comment: I'd largely argue that this is an unnecessary optimization, and that this is *unlikely* to be the part of your application which is slowing down.

Comment: Is the loop likely to iterate 3 times? or 100 times, or 100,000 times? That can make a difference in your decision. I also like to use a variable for documentation purposes — if I have a map of AccountID-to-PersonObject I would probably use something like `final Person accountHolder = accounts.get(acctNumber);`

Answer (score 2):

Retrieving a value from a `HashMap` is an O(1) operation, assuming your keys have a reasonable implementation of `hashCode()`.

If you're only retrieving this object a couple of times it may be a micro-optimization (read: premature optimization) to store it in a local variable, but you probably won't notice any difference either way. The real reason to store such an object in a local variable is to avoid duplicating boiler-plate code that checks the key really exists in the map, the value isn't `null`, etc.

Comment: +1 - however, even though a HashMap is O(1) there _is_ unavoidable overhead, as you say "checks the key really exists in the map" and computing the hashcode itself. I've "fixed" other peoples code where they retrieve the value from the map in a loop, and that is (IMO) clearly  a reason to store it in a (`final`) variable. Another reason I like is being able to name the variable appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing data in HashMap is O(1), so in general it's quite fast. However, if you initiate a variable with the proper value from the HashMap it would be a little bit faster. If you are accessing HashMap with some key, firstly hashCode method of the key is called. If you call that once - it would be faster.

My experience shows that preparing a variable for such cases is a better solution not only because of performance purposes but also because of refactoring. If it happened you had to change some code, you made one change in HashMap call instead of many in different lines, leaving often one line unchanged (which leads to a bug).

Answer (score 0):

HashMap get runs in constant time. So from efficiency point of view, it doesn't matter. Although storing the value in a variable is more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Calling hashmap.get() creates an indirection, therefor it's will be slower than a direct variable reference. The fact that hashmap.get() has O(1) complexity has absolutely nothing to do with the answer to this question, because O(1) complexity only means that the execution complexity of the algorithm does not increase with a growing number of elements, but, it does not say anything about how many cpu cycles a run takes, it only states that it's constant.
Storing the result in a variable would probably be the most performant.

Answer (score -1):

I've made a simple test with `HashMap<String, String>`, where both keys and values are random-generated 64-character strings. It uses 1.000.000 records in the map and goes through each of them in 2 for-loops: First is calling `get()` once and saving it to variable. Second is calling `get()` 3 times. This is done in 5 iterations.

Results (in milliseconds):

```
                      1    2    3    4    5      avg
Store in a variable: 125  126  103  104  102  |  112
Call 3 times:        151  135  137  134  152  |  142
```

So, for this configuration (map of string-string), calling `get()` once and storing result in a variable **is more effective**.

---

Code of the test:

```
ArrayList<String> keys;
HashMap<String, String> data;

void run() {
    generateData(1_000_000);

    long start, end;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (String key : keys) {
            String value = data.get(key);
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Store in a variable: " + ((end - start) / 1000 / 1000) + "ms");

        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (String key : keys) {
            data.get(key);
            data.get(key);
            data.get(key);
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Call 3 times: " + ((end - start) / 1000 / 1000) + "ms");
    }
}

void generateData(int size) {
    keys = new ArrayList<>(size);
    data = new HashMap<>(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        String key = getRandomString(64);
        keys.add(key);
        data.put(key, getRandomString(64));
    }
}

String getRandomString(int length) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        str.append((char) ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(128));
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```